# Recognize classical algebraic varieties as schemes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $V$ be a (classical) algebraic variety over an algebraically closed field $k$.
The set $X$, which consists of all the irreducible closed sets of $V$, is a scheme on $k$.
Hartshorne's proof doesn't seem to work unless $k$ is an algebraically closed field.
Is $X$ a scheme when $k$ is a field that is not algebraically closed?
If not, is there a way to recognize $V$ as a scheme?

In Hartshorne's book, the projective space $ \mathbb {P} ^ n_A $ on the ring $ A $ is defined using the fiber product.
I don't know how this complex definition works.

Let $ k $ be a non-algebraically closed field. $ \mathbb {P} ^ n_k $ uses the same symbols as the classic projective space definition, but can they be recognized as the same?

---

addition.
I came across the following description on wikipedia.
In scheme theory, the $n$-dimensional projective space over $k$ is
$$\mathbb{P}^n_k = \text{Proj} k [x_0, ..., x_n]$$
It is defined using a polynomial ring like this. The entire $k$-value point of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ matches the classical projective space.

Comment: What source do you have for classical varieties over non-algebraically closed fields? AFAIK, Hartshorne Chapter I assumes $k$ to be algebraically closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is easily done if $k$ is not algebraically closed. Consider for example
$$V = \mathbb R$$
as a variety over $\mathbb R$. Then the associated scheme ought to be $X = \mathbb A^1_{\mathbb R} = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb R[x]$, right? But the maximal ideal
$$(x^2 + 1) \subset \mathbb R[x]$$
does not correspond to any irreducible closed subset of $V$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I agree.

Added related questions.